# AngularJS: change a bool variable when changing states

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

pretty new to angularjs, looking on how to solve this problem.
I have this route:

```
name: "Tracker",
url: "/tracker/:period",
```

and I have 3 different states, for which I made 3 different functions so I can swap in my app from one url to another.

```
 viewYearly() { 
    this.$state.go("Tracker", {"period": 'year'});
    this.viewWeek = false;
    this.viewMonth = false;
    this.viewYear = true;
  };

viewMonthly() { 
    this.$state.go("Tracker", {"period": 'month'});
    this.viewWeek = false;
    this.viewMonth = true;
    this.viewYear = false;
  };  

viewWeekly() { 
    this.$state.go("Tracker", {"period": 'week'});
    this.viewWeek = true;
    this.viewMonth = false;
    this.viewYear = false;
  };
```

so the change of url works without issues, but I have a problem, I declared these 3 var:

```
viewWeek: boolean;
viewMonth: boolean;
viewYear: boolean;
```

in the controller so I can use them with ng-show to hide some content depending on what URL you are on.

As you can see in the 3 functions, I assign True depending on which url you are.

The problem I'm having, this is working but not correctly,
when I click on the button on my view to let's say change to Monthly url, the new url gets loaded, BUT the ng-show using the viewMonth variable only works after a SECOND click on the button.

So I click once, changes url, I click again, applies stuff using that bool.
I think the solution should be simple, something maybe on how I initialized those vars, any clue?

**Edit 1**: here the button to change url:

```
<div class="pull-right" ng-click="vm.viewYearly()"><i>View Year</i></div>
```

**Edit 2**:

```
views: {
      header: {
        templateUrl: "Views/Tracker/Header.htm",           
        controller: "trackerHeadCtrl",
        controllerAs: "vm"
```

**Edit 3** 
 **SOLUTION**:

I solved it like this at the end,

```
viewYearly() { 
this.$state.go("Tracker", {"period": 'year'});
```

this is the function to change state, and instead of declaring 3 bool vars and changing them, I used a function:

```
get viewMonth(): boolean {
        return this.period === "year";
    };
```

thank you for your answers anyway!

Comment: Can you post the button code (for one ought to be enough). Should be no problem, but may as well see it ...

Comment: Is this an state - independent controller ? If it's not, then probably after state changes the controller gets destroyed. Give us some more information.

Comment: edited with the button code!
I don't think it is (indipendent), but check the code of the routes resolve I put in the edit

Comment: Btw, I would recommend against using `this`, and get into the habit of using `$scope`

Comment: using 'this' where in my case? thank you for your answers

Comment: look at my latest edit

Comment: `this.viewWeek` - I wold have used `$scope.viewWeek` etc etc

Comment: shouldn't I put the BOOL variables into a  $scope.$watch? if that s the case, can someone help me write it with my code?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are updating `viewWeek`, `viewMonth`, `viewYear` outside of angular `$digest cirle`. To quickly fix you code, wrap the these lines inside `$timeout()` or `$scope.$applyAsync()`

Comment: thank you for the answer, can I ask you how do you mean to wrap the lines inside $scope.$applyAsync()?
could you give me an example with my code? I tried various things and they don't work, I think i m wrapping it in the wrong way

Answer (score 0):

You should be doing it another way round: click should change the state, and state will set the variables. Use state as your single source of truth.

```
  viewYearly() { 
    this.$state.go("Tracker", {"period": 'year'});
  };

  viewMonthly() { 
    this.$state.go("Tracker", {"period": 'month'});
  };  

  viewWeekly() { 
    this.$state.go("Tracker", {"period": 'week'});
  };

  //then at activate
  function activate() {
    if ($state.params.period == 'year') {
      // set variables here
    }
  }
```

Comment: not working, I still have to click twice on the button, first time it changes the URL, second time it does some stuff depending on the bool variable

Comment: how about adding a third param `true` to state.go to indicate you want a reload of the state?